# mysqli database connection error when using functions from different files

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a problem with the mysqli-connection not being open or used by functions which I include from other files. Look below at the setup. If I take all the code into one file, it works perfectly but in this way, nothing happens.

**connection.php**

```
<?php
function connect() {
    $db = new mysqli("host", "user", "pswrd", "database");
    return $db;
}
?>
```

**functions.php**

```
<?php
function get_user_email($user_id) {
    $sql = "SELECT email FROM user_acc WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
    if(!$result = $db->query($sql)) {die("woops!");}
    $data = $result->fetch_assoc();
    return $data['email'];
}
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
include("functions.php");
$db = connect();
echo get_user_email(1);
?>
```

Comment: please search on words `variable scope`.

Comment: OK, did that and tried adding the row: "global $db;" inside the function get_user_email() but didn't do it. Tried using $GLOBALS['db'] instead of $db inside the same function. Also didn't work... Also tried making the $db-variable global in the index.php file too, didn't help..

Comment: OK, after fixing an internal problem, the code is now working as it should by adding "global $db;" at the top of the function get_user_email(). ty YCS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by changing the file functions.php:

```
<?php
function get_user_email($user_id) {
    global $db; //This is what was needed!
    $sql = "SELECT email FROM user_acc WHERE user_id='$user_id'";
    if(!$result = $db->query($sql)) {die("woops!");}
    $data = $result->fetch_assoc();
    return $data['email'];
}
?>
```

Thank you Your Common Sense for supplying the indirect answer that lead to answering this uestion  ;)